# Number of possible events is $2^N$ ( $N$ is the number of outcomes )?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A probability space is a random process or experiment with
three components:
–

$Ω,$ the set of possible outcomes $O$

*number of possible outcomes = $|Ω| = N$

*$F$, the set of possible events $E$
      - an event comprises $0$ to
$N$ outcomes

- number of possible events
  = $| F | = 2^N$

Here I am not able to extract the exact meaning of number of possible outcomes. In case of tossing a coin, we have only $2$ outcomes. So, $N = 2$. So, either we have head or tail. According to the above definition, $|F| = 2^N = 2^2 = 4.$ How come this formula or axiom is valid in probability space ?

Comment: Perhaps they meant that if you have $N$ independent events (in one-dimensional probability space) with $k$ outcomes (for coin tossing $k=2$, for common dice $k=6$, for roulette $k=37$ or $38$ depending on country) and repeat the experiment $N$ times, then you will have exactly $k^N$ events (in $N-$dimensional probability space) in total. This is not working for some dependent one-dimensional events when elements are removed after they are selected, so you will have less than $k^N$ possible events in related probability spaces.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by drhabs is wrong, his answer misses the null set. 2^n comes from the fact that for each element in your set you have 2 choices, to either include or not include it in a subset. For the example Ω={H,T} you will have the following subsets:

- {H,T} (every set is a subset of it's self)
- {H}
- {T}
- {} (null set)

Comment: I am not sure why ppl downvoting

Comment: The downvotes may be because drhab's answer is correct -- he just refers to the same above four events as "a head is thrown" $(\{H\}),$ "a tail is thrown" $(\{T\}),$ "a head **and** a tail is thrown" $(\{H\}\cap\{T\}=\{\}=\emptyset,$ and "a head **or** a tail is thrown" $(\{H\}\cup\{T\}=\{H,T\}=\Omega.$

Answer (score 3):

In the situation you sketch we have $\Omega=\{H,T\}$ where $H$ stands for head and $T$ for tail.

There are $2$ possible outcomes and there are $2^2=4$ events:

- a head is thrown
- a tail is thrown
- a head and a tail is thrown (has probability $0$)
- a head or a tail is thrown (has probability $1$)

I am not sure whether this answers your question, but I hope this makes things more clear for you.

Comment: But its a case of one toss as per the definition in my question. i got it from university of washington notes. So, if we are tossing only once, how come "a head and tail is thrown". I suppose you mean "and" as getting both outcomes.

Comment: Not very likely indeed to throw a head **and** a tail by one toss. That is exactly the reason why it has probability $0$. The theory somehow says: we don't exclude it, but just give it this probability $0$ to repair that.

Comment: ok. I got a slight idea. It may happen or may not. If it happens, it has 2 outcomes(either head or tail). So, in the probabilistic perspective, should we consider the chances of whether it happens or not. How can we consider it as outcomes? Outcomes occur if experiement is successful. I am rookie in the area. So, if I am talking rubbish, please dont mind.

Comment: By an experiment (throwing a toss or a die) we must built an appropriate mathematical model and start with a set of outcomes. Based on those outcomes we have events as sets of outcomes. The event "occurs" if the outcome lands in the set that is linked to that event.

Answer (score 0):

an event is different from an outcome.

You have also the event "the coin land" $= E$ and the event "the coin doesn't land" $= \emptyset$

Take a dice, it's more clear : You can roll 1 to 6, but an event can be "roll an even number" or "roll a number under 5"

Comment: So you are telling, if i throw a dice I can get a even or odd ( as an example case ). I thought the same way initailly. But what hits me was, to take the chance of possibility of getting odd number say (1,3,5), we have to throw the dice 3 times. But the definition in the question holds for number of possible outcomes. they are not mentioning the number of times we have to perform an experiment.

Comment: An event is different from an outcome. The event is "getting an odd number", so any number in {1,3,5} is in the event (you can say "realise the event")

Comment: @user3116355 You can get an odd number by throwing the die only once.

Comment: @Tryss - I got it. Suppose we are having three outcomes say {a,b,c}. So, N = 3. Events E = 2^N=2^3 =8. So, events is the subset of outcomes. So we will have: [{a,b,c},{a},{b},{c},{a,b},{a,c},{b,c},{Nullset}]. So total 8 subsets.

Comment: @drhab - Please check the answer above.

Comment: @user3116355 Correct. Here every subset of the "outcome set" is an event. in further theory that is not necessary and you will meet $\sigma$-algebras. But that's for later.

Answer (score 0):

The set of possible events $F$ has to be the collection of all sets which can be constructed from the individual outcomes using the set operations of union and intersection. $F$ is basically the set of all subsets of $\Omega$, so $F$ has size $2^{|\Omega|}$.

Comment: "has to be" and "basically" are a bit too strong. However, within this context it is okay.

Comment: Good point. We can construct the probability measure in a number of ways deciding which subsets are measurable or not. For a discrete random variable with $n$ outcomes such as the example here, it will always be exactly $2^n$, yes? Of course many of those events could have measure zero.

Answer (score 0):

*number of possible outcomes = |Ω|=N
The above statement should be the following
number of possible outcomes "in an experiment" = |Ω|=N

Then, everything would be clear.

In the case of tossing a coin, if you do two times then N = 2.
Sample space is equal 2^2 = 4.
The elements would be [(H,T),(T,H),(T,T),(H,H)].

Answer (score -1):

Lets first see what an event means.
An event is not one outcome, but is a set.
For example in a problem of tossing a coin, the outcomes are $H$ & $T.$ 
So the outcome set (Lets say $O$) , $O = \{H,T\}.$
Now an event is a subset of $O$, which means that it will contain the nullset, each single outcome and their combinations. i.e $E$ (all possible events) = $\{0,H,T,\{H,T\}\}.$

To understand why the number of events is equal to $2^N$ , lets take a outcome set $O$ having $N$ elements.
Null set can be selected in $1$ way
A event with one out the $N$ outcomes will be selected in $N$ ways,
with $2$ of the outcomes in NC2 ways and so on
when you add all of them,
its the binomial expansion of $2^N.$

Answer (score -1):

$2^N$ is very special. It describes so much and is a key to understanding something truly magical.

An event that can only have $2$ outcomes and more so, can occur equally likely, event conducted in a fair setting. Fair as in pure, without any bias or favouring either of the outcome deliberately! Conducting a trial, Bernulli trial, determining an answer, detecting level of responsiveness.

Fundamentally, during the occurrence of the most simplest event possible, there are only $2$ possible states for this event to be in. At any given time of conducting a measurement the event has not yet occured or it already has.

Consider a sequence, of question -> answer pairs:

Has the event occured? No

Has the event occured? No

Has the event occured? Yes

Has the event occured? Yes

Has the event occured? No

In such case the ratio of number of No's and Yes's observed will be equal

Any sequnce of events with $2$ possible states of outcome has a chance of being observed once in $2^N$ number of trials.

$$\frac12 \times \frac12 \times \ldots = \frac1{2^N}$$

Knowing this it is possible to "game the system".

Here's the simplest thought experiment illustrating the situation if this exploitation occurring. In a way one can use randomness against itself like this:

Decide on the outcome in advance (Red) and conduct the experiment (Throw the ball).

Has the ball stopped on Red? No

Has the ball stopped on Red? No

Has the ball stopped on Red? No

Has the ball stopped on Red? No

Has the ball stopped on Red? Yes

Bet $1$ is $\$1$. Loss. Total loss is $\$1$

Bet $2$ is $\$2$. Loss. Total loss $1+2=3$

Bet $3$ is $\$4$. Loss. Total loss $+4=7$

Bet $4$ is $\$8$. Loss. Total loss $+8=15$

Bet $5$ is $\$16$. Win. Total win is equal to my original $\$16$ used to place bet 5 coming back, plus the win itself. Win equal to the amount I placed on 5th coin toss and $16 additional. Bringing my total win to $32=$16+$16

Lets count our chickens.

Our total loss was $\$15$ the casino took it and that money is not coming back. $-\$15$.
Win is $+\$32$. Assume original $\$16$ were borrowed from a friend to play in casino. So we return his money back $-\$16$ and keep the other earned $\$16$ to ourselves. We've spent $\$15$ out of our pocket to play the coin toss game and ended up with $\$16$ so our net win $-\$15+\$16=\$1$.

Introducing a particular notation O(n)=1 means even if you throw n number of tosses and lose -$X amount and win back +$Y amount you'll end up with -$X+$Y=$1 always at the end.

Next time you throw the coin 4 times and in that circumstance lose 3x but win on the 4th you'll lose -$7 and win +$8 you'll end up now with $2 extra.

Here's what I mean:

Consider a sequence of 5+3 coin tosses:
[Loss Loss Loss Loss Win Loss Loss Win]  or simply [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1] shows after observing 2 wins you'll end up with $2 extra.

So again O(n)=1 means tossing the coin n times so long as a win at the end has occured will always bring $1 extra.

I keep increasing my bet at the rate of 2 times the previously placed bet so eventually a win is observed and I end up with an extra $1 or an extra unit if your initial bet was not $1 but something else.

The next bet after a win (6th flip or 9th flip) will be back to $1 since we reset the event and start anew.

2^N-1 is also an important formula. It is the total sum, the closed form solution to the SUM(2^N). At any given point in time the total loss is 2^N-1. The sequence of N losses is equal to $2^N-1 dollars.

What if we don't double?

Bet $1$ is $\$1$. Loss. Total loss is $-\$1$

Bet $2$ is $\$3$. Loss. Total loss $-4$

Bet $3$ is $\$7$. Loss. Total loss $-\$11$

Bet $4$ is $\$15$. Loss. Total loss $-26$

Bet $5$ is $\$31$. Win. Total win is $2\times\$31=62$. Net profit $\$-(26+31)+2\times31=+\$5$

Number of flips is $5$. Profit for this batch of flips is $5$.

Bet $6$ is $\$1$. Loss. Total loss is $-1$

Bet $7$ is $\$3$. Loss. Total loss $-4$

Bet $8$ is $\$7$. Win. Total loss is $-11$, total win is $\$14$ so net profit is $-11+14=3$.

Number of flips is $3$. Total profit is $3$ for the second batch of flips.

Total profit is $5+3=8$. Total number of flips is $8$.

Using the introduced notation above $O(n)=n$.

This would mean flip a coin $5$ times and bet $\$100$ on the first flip, the total profit will be $\$500$. Flip another $3$ times, another $\$300$. So long as you can sustain your bets that grow exponentially once a win is observed total number will always be equal to n. So $f(x)=x$.

Now think about $\mathcal{O}(n)=n^2$
Here flip a coin $5$ times and win $\$2500$ plus $\$900$ if you flip another $3$ times.

Comment: not the downvoter but maybe I am missing something, most part of the answer seem to digress from answering the question to me.